# Compare two Android profiler trace

Tags: android, diff, trace, android-profiler

Is there a way to compare two android profiler traces?  I am trying to find out my my build X is faster to load than Y.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported in Android Studio profilers yet.

I assume you're talking about CPU traces, correct? If so, are you interested in comparing two traces manually or programmatically (e.g. CD/CI)?

Would you be comparing them by timeline or aggregated statistics (avg, min, max, etc.)?

Head on over to Android [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533) and open a feature request with your requirements? The profiler team would like to hear about them. Thanks.